# Has anyone used Grocery CRUD and jQuery File Upload script?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, image-uploading, grocery-crud

I desperately need to make the Grocery CRUD (Codeigniter) to be able to use multiple image upload with thumbnail preview for the uploaded images.

jQuery File Upload is what I need, but I really don't know how to integrate it or use it together with grocery crud. Maybe I will implement it somehow in the footer let's say, but even I did that, I have no idea how to pass the values (names of uploaded images) to grocery crud to enter them in the database...

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Or maybe there is some smarter way to do this...

Grocery Image CRUD doesn't work well, it can't be implemented in the same view... Plus it is almost impossible to combine those two libraries together...

Comment: Have you tried posting in the grocery crud support forum?

Comment: Here is the same question, but no answer.
http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/1402-has-anyone-used-grocery-crud-and-jquery-file-upload-script/

Here is something similar to combine with the Grocery image library, but still no one succeeded.
http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/1326-how-to-use-grocery-crud-and-image-crud-together/